# react-google-maps: dynamically highlight a country or a subntaional

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, geojson, topography

I use a react-google-maps and I want to dynamically highlight a country or a subntaional when user click on the map anywhere in the whole world, so I need to get coordinates to draw a polygon, but can't find any service with api for it. What the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

I was also searching for this solution. you can use google charts api for above problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Please use this API.

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=US&polygon_geojson=1&format=json

It will return multiPolygon array.